# Chrome failing to load certificate on OS X

Tags: macos, ssl, x509certificate

Users are reporting that they can't view https://blog.za3k.com on OS X.
Chrome and Safari (which use OS X's root certificates fail).

All tests of Linux and Windows have shown no problems. Qualys SSL Labs reports no problems except SHA1 signatures.

Chrome reports `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID` and if I click the certificate icon -> View certificate, I see `The data does not appear to be a valid certificate`

Firefox loads the page correctly.
Safari hangs on visiting the page.
OS X version has no effect that I can tell, but I'm on 10.10.1 personally.

`curl https://blog.za3k.com` fails with:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
  bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
  using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

`openssl s_client -connect blog.za3k.com:443` reports success

The root certificate is 'StartCom', which should be trusted on mac.

Ideas on how to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you seeing in the certificate data which you're returned?  Here things are a bit curious -- from a desktop system I see a certificate returned for 'nanowrimo.za3k.com' or 'za3k.com' (but *not* blog.za3k.com), while obviously SSLLabs sees a certificate which is valid for blog.za3k.com and za3k.com.  Could be a DNS aliasing issue, but really the cert should contain a SAN for whatever you mean it to appear as.

```
openssl s_client -connect blog.za3k.com:443 | openssl x509 -text
```

Comment: Aha, thanks for alerting me. I'm using SNI to host multiple domains from the same IP, and it looks like the openssl s_client doesn't support SNI. I changed the default and openssl s_client should return the relevant certificate so you can take a look. I still see the same error in curl, Chrome, and Safari, so it wasn't related.

Comment: Ahh, well that helps.  In the end you're using an 8k public key, support for which is disabled by default in OSX.  Solution available here: [link]http://blog.shiz.me/post/67305143330/8192-bit-rsa-keys-in-os-x[/link].

For a public site, though, you might consider regenerating at 4096 RSA or just switching to ECDSA.

Comment: This blog post is great, because it also has all the debugging steps I could have used to find out what was going on. Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it as /the/ correct answer?